# Android TimePickerDialog not displaying 24-hour format for certain locales?

Tags: android, localization, android-timepicker

I'm working on internationalizing my app, and I've been setting my device to different locales and testing out the `TimePickerDialog` to make sure that it displays the time pickers in the correct format for that locale.

It displays the correct time pickers for U.S. (AM/PM) format.

For Germany, I expected it to display the time picker in 24-hour format, but instead it displays it in 12-hour format with vorm./nachm. options.

But the one I am really confused about is when I set my device locale to French, the time picker displays time in a 12-hour format with AM/PM, just like for the U.S.  I would have also expected this to display the pickers in 24-hour format.

Is this the expected behavior for a `TimePickerDialog`?

Answer (score 4):

Okay I just found the solution.

The final argument to the constructor for `TimePickerDialog` lets you specify a boolean called `is24HourView`.

So you can check this dynamically using:

```
TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(
            getActivity(),
            this, 
            hour, 
            minute, 
            DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
```